# What is the maximum length of Firebase a user property value?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm passing along some client-generated user properties into Firebase Analytics and encountered the following message in logcat:

> W/FA: Value is too long; discarded. Value kind, name, value length: user property, comp0, 37
>   D/FA: Logging event (FE): error(_err), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_error_length(_el)=37, firebase_error_value(_ev)=comp0, firebase_error(_err)=7}]

I looked up error code 7 [in the Firebase Analytics Error Codes page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/errors), and while it reveals that the code means "user property value is too long", it doesn't specify what the maximum length is.

What's the maximum length of user property values? Is there a maximum length for key names, too?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [documentation for FirebaseAnalytics.UserProperty](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.UserProperty) reveals the answer:

> UserProperty names can be up to 24 characters long, may only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores ("_"), and must start with an alphabetic character. UserProperty values can be up to 36 characters long.

Comment: That's for ANdroid. Same for iOS?

Comment: Yes, the [iOS documentation states the same restrictions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/api/reference/Classes/FIRAnalytics).

Comment: It says 100 characters for NSString on that page.

Comment: Can a device be linked to more than one userProperty value? I mean, if for example in the same application I can switch from an account to another, and I will set the userProperty depending on the account in order to send custom push. Will it be possible?

Comment: The property accepts one value and is identified by the instance ID, which is derived from the application installation. Depending on your use case, you can define audiences in the Firebase console such that a device joins an audience if the user property has _ever been_ a specific value. This may or may not be what you're looking for as this approach doesn't permit users to voluntarily exit that audience.